# Exception on API Key of Google Maps API for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, api-key

I am developing an iOS app using Google Maps API for IOS. And I installed the CocoaPod for my project and configure them according to tutorial on Google Developer. However, when I run my project, it says

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GMSServicesException', reason: 'Google Maps SDK for iOS must > be initialized via [GMSServices provideAPIKey:...] prior to use'

But I already call "GMSServices.provideAPIKey on the AppDelegate.swift. Following is the code:

```
....
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("***********************")
    return true
}
....
```

(**************) is my API Key.

And because Google Maps API use Objective C, so I created a Bridging Header to import the library.

I tried to set breakpoint on [application:didFinishLaunchingWithOption]. But it will raise exception before run that function, which I think is very weird.

So confused about it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The exception happen only if you didnt include `GMSServices.provideAPIKey()` in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, you should paste all the lines from your AppDelegate file.

Answer (score 5):

Problem finally solved, the reason is that I initialize a fields using Google Maps library in the one model class and it will be created before the app run. So this error happens. When I moved this variable into the method, problem solved. Following is the code that causes error:

```
class PlaceManager {
    let placeClient = GMSPlacesClient()
    ...
    func getSuggestions(queryString:String) -> [String]{
        ...
    }
}
```

After

```
class PlaceManager {
    func getSuggestions(queryString:String) -> [String]{
        let placeClient = GMSPlacesClient()
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**, move the call to **willFinishLaunchingWithOptions**. This method is called after state restoration has occurred but before your app’s window and other UI have been presented. (Which in your case might be a UI that consumes Google Map API)

```
func application(application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
GMSServices.provideAPIKey("***********************")

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem.  I created a GMSMapView object and it was initialized before maybe the api key could be read. So I moved it inside the viewDidLoad method and problem solved.

Before :

```
class ViewController: ..... {

let mapView = GMSMapView()
```

After :

```
class ViewController: ..... {

var mapView : GMSMapView?

override viewDidLoad(){
    mapView = GMSMapView()
```

Comment: This is the same response that someone else already gave.  Consider upvoting that answer rather than adding your own.

Comment: This is it. This solved my problem when I already have an API key attached to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Answer (score 0):

In your appDelegate.m at didFinishLaunchingWithOptions this add these GMSService line with api key for me it worked.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"**************"];
  [FIRApp configure];
}
```

and add this import at the top

```
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
```

Comment: I don't think this addresses the original 'GMSServicesException'.