# Google Maps iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, google-maps-sdk-ios

This is my code

```
import UIKit    
import GooglePlaces  
import GoogleMaps  
@UIApplicationMain  

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

   GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("************************")
   GMSServices.provideAPIKey("************************")

    return true
}
```

but I'm still getting the exception

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GMSServicesException',
>   reason: 'Google Maps SDK for iOS must be initialized via [GMSServices
>   provideAPIKey:...] prior to use'

Is there any other cause, help me to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception on API Key of Google Maps API for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32812685/exception-on-api-key-of-google-maps-api-for-ios)

Comment: What can I do ?

Comment: post your controller code

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/42589391/5594218

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewController class is calling before appDelegate. So, the APIKey was not initiated. After finding this I initiate the viewController in appDelegate.

Comment: I am finding the same issue - that the ViewController class is being loaded before appDelegate.  Can you please elaborate on your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You must add API Key in **App delegate** and implement GoogleMap delegate in ViewController

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

let googleApiKey = "<YOUR API Key HERE>"

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey(googleApiKey)
        return true
    }
//other methods
}
```

and your **ViewController** should be like

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    // MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

        guard status == .authorizedWhenInUse else {
            return
        }
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        guard let location = locations.first else {
            return
        }

        mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

> **PS**: Make sure you don't forget these important steps.

1. Go to  [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/?pli=1) and create app and API Key
2. **Enable APIs** for Google Maps SDK for iOS
3. Add privacy permissions in **.Plist file**

---

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Application requires user’s location information while the app is running in the foreground.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Will you allow this app to always know your location?</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Do you allow this app to know your current location?</string>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I placed a breakpoint at the start of the AppDelegate class and it's not getting called so it's not picking up the APIKey.